# Validation for inserting duplicate entries is not working using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I Have written a query for validating the email ids to not accept the duplicate emails while inserting into database.But it is not working and inserting duplicate email ids into database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_user'])){

     $email = $_POST['user_email'];
      $check=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where user_email='$email'");
      $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);
      if($checkrows>0) {
  echo "Email Already exists";
   } else {  

    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['con_password']){

        $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

        $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, user_email, user_password, user_gender, user_marital_status, user_phone_no, user_designation,user_address,user_date,user_role,username) VALUES ('$_POST[first_name]', '$_POST[last_name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[marital_status]', '$_POST[phone_no]', '$_POST[designation]', '$_POST[address]', '$date','$_POST[user_role]' , '$_POST[username]')";

        $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql);

    }else {

        $match = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Password doesn&apos;t match!</div>';

    }
 }
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: in insert you use `$_POST[email]` and in the select `$_POST['user_email']` maybe this is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking wrong email id. change `$email = $_POST['user_email'];` to `$email = $_POST['email'];`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_user'])){

   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $check=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where user_email='$email'");
   $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);
   if($checkrows>0) {
      echo "Email Already exists";
   } else {
    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['con_password']){
        $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, user_email, user_password, user_gender, user_marital_status, user_phone_no, user_designation,user_address,user_date,user_role,username) VALUES ('$_POST[first_name]', '$_POST[last_name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[marital_status]', '$_POST[phone_no]', '$_POST[designation]', '$_POST[address]', '$date','$_POST[user_role]' , '$_POST[username]')";
        $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql);
    }else {
        $match = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Password doesn&apos;t match!</div>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine but if we enter duplicate email id it is not displaying any message as email already exists or not

Comment: if the record exists then it should show the echo message that email already exists

Comment: so is it going in if condition? have you checked it?

Comment: yes it is checking the condition if the email exists then not inserting into database

Comment: okay so you can't echo message in thi. share your html code so i get idea.

Comment: just want to know regarding the message